# Java ProcessBuilder is not able to start GNU screen

Tags: java, shell, processbuilder, gnu-screen

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour of java's ProcessBuilder.
What I try is to stop a running screen using a shell, delete a few folders and after that restart the screen using another shell script.
The first step, killing the running screen, runs perfectly using:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb0 = new ProcessBuilder(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/generator/stop.sh");
```

In this stop.sh shell I simply run

> screen -X -S generator kill

which works as it should.
After that I delete my directorys using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils and then I want to start the screen again. Currently I'm doing it like that:

```
    System.out.println("Restarting the generator");

    ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder();
    pb1.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/generator"));
    pb1.command("./start.sh");
    try {
        Process process = pb1.start();
        System.out.printf("Started the generator with %d", process.waitFor());
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This gives out "Started the generator with 1" which indicates to me that the screen runs which is simply not the case when checking with screen -ls.
No errors, no clue on how to move forward from here

Inside start.sh:

```
screen -S generator java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar generator.jar
```

PS: I'm using Debian 10.
Maybe anyone can help me out here?
Greets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never ignore process output, because it's buffer has limited length, and if you don't consume it, it will hang. Im not sure if this is causing your issue, but this is definitely something you should do.

It is also possible that process throws some error that you can't see because you are ignoring it's output (in which case, this will help you to investigate the issue).

Try this:

```java
new ProcessBuilder()
  .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
  .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
  ...
```

This will redirect process output stream and input stream to it's parent (which is your application).

Comment: I've added your suggestion to my existing code and there ya go. A new error occurs!
I totally forgot that my code runs in a screen already and therefore the start.sh was not connected to a terminal.
I changed -S to -dmS and everything is working as it should

Thanks